# UIToolbar accessory view for UITextField unresponsive

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I'm building a `UITextField` that uses a `UIPickerView` to allow users to select from a list of states. In order to dismiss the view, I tried adding a `UIToolbar` as an accessory view to this input that contains a `UIBarButton` that responds to an action to dismiss the input view. Here's the code for it:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Load state names.
    NSString* file = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"States" ofType:@"plist"];
    self.states = [[NSArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:file];

    // Initialize the picker view.
    self.picker = [[UIPickerView alloc] init];
    [self.picker setDelegate:self];

    // Initialize the button view.
    toolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc] init];
    [toolbar setDelegate:self];
    [toolbar setBarStyle:UIBarStyleDefault];

    done = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Done" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone target:self action:@selector(resignFocus:)];

    [toolbar setItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:done, nil] animated:YES];

    // Set the picker view as the state field input view.
    // Also set the done button as it's accessory.
    [[self state] setInputView:self.picker];
    [[self state] setInputAccessoryView:self.toolbar];
}
```

With this code when I begin editing the specific text field the picker and toolbar both appear. The problem is that I can't interact with the button - there's no indication that taps get through to it. The button doesn't get highlighted like buttons should and the action is never fired. Is it possible that the picker view is somehow overlapping the toolbar, preventing input from reaching it?

I'm developing this for iOS7 and I'm using the simulator to test it.

Comment: Yes.Most likely something is overlapping the button.

Answer (score 3):

UIToolbar doesn't have a default frame, so your toolbar's size is {0, 0}. Its clipsToBounds is NO by default, which is why you can see the Done button. Give the toolbar a frame and your button should start working.